# How to get sum of all elements in json using Scala?

Tags: json, list, scala

I have following Json-

```
"disks" : [ {
    "name" : "v2.16",
    "diskAggregate" : "aggr0",
    "diskRPM" : 15000,
    "totalSizeBytes" : 1077477376,
    "vendorId" : "NETAPP  ",
    "usedBytes" : 1070071808,
    "diskType" : "FCAL",
    "uuid" : "4E455441:50502020:56442D31:3030304D:422D465A:2D353230:32353836:30303030:00000000:00000000",
    "portName" : "FC:A ",
    "raidGroup" : "rg0"
}, 
{
    "name" : "v4.16",
    "diskAggregate" : "aggr0",
    "diskRPM" : 15000,
    "totalSizeBytes" : 1077477376,
    "vendorId" : "NETAPP  ",
    "usedBytes" : 1070071808,
    "diskType" : "FCAL",
    "uuid" : "4E455441:50502020:56442D31:3030304D:422D465A:2D353230:32353633:34333030:00000000:00000000",
    "portName" : "FC:B ",
    "raidGroup" : "rg0"
}]
```

I want to get addition of usedBytes from all json objects from json array 'disks'.
I tried out it with fold in Scala but didn't get desired output.
here is my code -

```
val datastoreCapacity = disks
val usableSpace = datastoreCapacity.foldLeft(0L) {
    case (sumOfUsedSpace, esxDevice) =>
      val sumOfTotalBytesOnStorageDevice = esxDevice.datastores.foldLeft(0L) {
        case (totalBytesOnDevice, datastore) =>
         // totalBytesOnDevice + ut..getOrElse(0L).toString.toLong
        val sum = datastore.utilization.foldLeft(0L) {
          case (total,util) =>
            total + util.usedBytes.getOrElse(0L).toString.toLong
        }
      }
      sumOfUsedSpace + sumOfTotalBytesOnStorageDevice
  }
```

How do I get total of used bytes using Scala?

Answer (score 2):

assuming that disks is a list of already parsed objects with a getter called usedBytes returning option of Long (as your code suggests), this should do:

```
disks.map(_.usedBytes).flatten.sum
```

some explanation:

- with `map` we transform all objects with the given lambda function (which essentially just calls the getter `usedBytes`).
- `flatten` filters out all `None`s and leaves the values of `Some`s in the list. (Can also be used on lists of lists or arrays of vectors etc. etc.)
- `sum` just does what it says and builds the `sum` of a collection of numeric values (which we get as a result from `flatten`)

---

Guessing from your comment I assume that despite your example data above, disks have an attribute utilization. I don't know what that looks like, and what it means because that is unclear from your question but if I assume that it is again a list with disks. Then you could do the following

```
disks.flatMap(_.utilization.map(_.usedBytes).flatten).sum
```

Please specify what data you want to process if this isn't what you where looking for.

Comment: It will traverse to only datastore.. how to access key inside 'utilization'?

Comment: @Vishwas what do you mean by 'utilization'?  if you want complete answer you should post the data model classes